# Symfony2: Access anonymously path

Tags: authentication, symfony, anonymous

I use the FOSRestbundle with mopa/wsse-authentication-bundle (WSSE authentication).

Everything works fine (Authentication and RESTful api).
But i want to make 1 specific path public (without authentication).

Path i want to make public: ^/api/users

I tried following settings but i still get a 403 Forbidden status for the api/users path.
(security.yml)

```
    jms_security_extra:
            secure_all_services: false
            expressions: true

    security:
            encoders:
                    ***\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

            role_hierarchy:
                    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_API_USER]

            providers:
                    ***_users:
                            entity: { class: UserBundle:User }

            firewalls:
                    wsse_secured:
                            pattern:   ^/api
                            anonymous: true
                            stateless:  true
                            wsse:
                                    nonce_dir: null
                                    lifetime: 300
                                    provider: ***_users

            access_control:
                    - { path: ^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                    - { path: ^/(css|js), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                    - { path: ^/(_wdt|_profiler)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make api/users/ page public that is accessible to everybody without any sort of authentication, you can think of keeping out of WSSE authentication. To do that, you can specify the url pattern for which WSSE authentication will not be applied. e.g. in below example I have specified a pattern to skip URLs having the form as "api/users/".

in short I am suggesting to skip WSSE authentication for the "users" page using the "pattern"

```
wsse_secured:
            pattern:   ^/api/[^users].*
            wsse:
                 nonce_dir: null
                 lifetime: 300
                 provider: ***_users
```